# Multi level dictionary Performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary, optimization

Recently, I started working on a C# .NET project that requires to keep a Dictionary of words in Memory.

My first approach was to create a

```
Dictionary<string, string>
```

(where the Key would be the word and Value the definition).

That worked well, and after a while I decided to try using "buckets" and went for a

```
Dictionary<char, Dictionary<string, string>>
```

Where the char is the first letter of the words inside the inner Dictionary.

My question is: Do I really have a performance gain by applying this change? (And making the code more complex)

I'm aware Dictionary is supposed to be O(1), so in theory it would be the same for 5 words or 2 million. And by adding multiple levels I would be duplicating the lookup time.

Thanks!

Comment: On the surface, this is likely to make things slower.  I recommend doing some performance tests of your own to find out for sure.

Comment: First, as @user5151179 points out, the only way to find out is to actually measure it. Second, and perhaps, more importantly: See if you actually _have_ a performance problem, before thinking about optimizing.

Comment: [Horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert answer your question. Please read it and update post if you still have a problem

Comment: IMHO Dictionary already uses buckets internally. See source code here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0

Comment: Thanks gdir, exactly my initial thought, that's the way dictionary works, with constant access-time lookup tables. What I don't know is how the Dictionary figures what buckets to use. Maybe by doing the initial buckets myself I would be "helping" it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many factors at work here. By splitting your data per letter you inject a lot more lookups into unrelated types that need to be cached by your CPU. You're more likely to thrash the cache instead and get terrible performance.

On the other hand if you have *a lot* of entries relatively equally distributed across their first letters, and if you don't look up uniformly but focus on just a few letters, then you're likely to get an increase in lookup performance.

And as a last note, I don't know where you got the idea that dictionary lookup (or dictionary anything) is O(1), you might want to consider looking at that. It's bound to make your decisions down the line incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Blindy, so in response to your note: 

The Hashtable class (and by extension, any Dictionary<TKey,TValue>) has O(1) performance at the slight expense of memory usage (Lookup Tables). O(1) means the time to get a value (if no collisions) is Constant.

Comment: It's the "if no collisions" part that's important here. Dictionary lookup is not O(1). You can argue it's *optimistically* O(1), but that's a generally useless metric.

Comment: Exactly! So would something like what I'm proposing help avoid collisions? What do you think would happen? (this is all in theory of course, I can go and test it like some comments have been suggesting, but I'd like to be able to interpret the results I'm getting). Would the constant time to access the look-up table improve by having smaller buckets?

Comment: It wouldn't, hence the "And as a last note". It's unrelated. It was a reply to your conviction that, and I quote, "I'm aware Dictionary is supposed to be O(1)". There has never been such a requirement on any dictionary implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - NO, you would not improve performance of the hash table by splitting it. And, as you noted, you would ALWAYS do multiple look-ups.

To improve performance you need to reduce number of collisions. Assuming that the hashing function is the same, the only thing you can alter is the load factor. As always, the speed comes at the price of the space.

Ignoring an overhead, in the same space you can create one table with 1,000 buckets or ten - with 100. Placing a 1,000 items in it will give you the load factor of 1.0 for the big one, ans an *average* of 1.0 for the little ones. The "lucky" table will have better performance, the other - worth. Add a time for an extra look-up to that...

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I'm in the process of writing a test to see how it performs and will share the results once it's done. At that point I'll choose the correct answer.